# Can we integrate iFrame in PHP file?

Tags: php

Can we integrate iframes in PHP files ?

If so, can anyone please provide an example.

Thanks in advance.

Merci,
Serenity.

Comment: To what end? And what do you mean by integrate?

Comment: This is clearly a case of needing to read what an iFrame does, and what PHP does before lazily asking on a board and frustrating the masses.

Comment: I would like to add Delicious tags to my PHP file.

Comment: Delicious tags are generated in iFrames and now I need to add the iFrame to my PHP file.

Comment: Then i would go ahead and read the Delicious documentation on how to use their API.  Also i would be very descriptive and provide details (like you are trying to use the delicious API in your project) in your original question.  Once those tasks are completed ask a well formed question with a basis looking for a direct answer about something that isn't as broad as, how do i IFrame this file??

Answer (score 3):

You are misunderstanding what PHP does. PHP is used to generate HTML (among other things). Seeing as you can have an iFrame in a HTML file, I guess the answer to your question is "yes".

You are probably better off describing what you want to do to get more detailed advice.

Answer (score 1):

Surely, you would just use

```
print '<iframe></iframe>';
```

Is that what you mean?

It's important to note that you don't need to use this method. You can write HTML directly in the source, you don't need to print it using PHP.